# R: Finding Out Which Students are Improving Their Grade

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following dataset of student grades:

```
my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), year = c(2010,2011,2012,2013, 2014, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), grade = c(55, 56, 61, 61, 62, 90,89,89, 67, 87, 51, 65))

> my_data
   id year grade
1   1 2010    55
2   1 2011    56
3   1 2012    61
4   1 2013    61
5   1 2014    62
6   2 2008    90
7   2 2009    89
8   2 2010    89
9   3 2018    67
10  3 2019    87
11  3 2020    51
12  3 2021    65
```

**My Question:** I want to find out which students improved their grades (or kept the same grade) from year to year, and which students got worse grades from year to year.

Using the idea of "grouped window functions", I tried to write the following functions :

```
check_grades_improvement <- function(grades){
  for(i in 2:length(grades)){
    if(grades[i] < grades[i-1]){
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

check_grades_decline <- function(grades){
  for(i in 2:length(grades)){
    if(grades[i] > grades[i-1]){
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
```

Then, I tried to apply these functions to my dataset:

```
  improving_students <- my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(check_grades_improvement(grade)) %>% 
  select(id) %>% 
  unique()


worse_students <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(check_grades_decline(grade)) %>% 
  select(id) %>% 
  unique()
```

**But I am getting empty results**

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your expected output.  Your function is checking each row, so it can either be TRUE or FALSE in some years.  Did you meant to return at the first instance where the grades of next year is greater than previous year (or likewise smaller than previous year)

Comment: So with more than 2 years you need to define "improve". up-down-up? Is that improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(x = grade-lag(grade, default = grade[1])) %>% 
  mutate(peformance = case_when(x == 0 ~ "kept_same",
                                x > 0 ~ "improved",
                                x < 0 ~ "got_worse",
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_), .keep="unused")
```

```
     id  year grade peformance
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
 1     1  2010    55 kept_same 
 2     1  2011    56 improved  
 3     1  2012    61 improved  
 4     1  2013    61 kept_same 
 5     1  2014    62 improved  
 6     2  2008    90 kept_same 
 7     2  2009    89 got_worse 
 8     2  2010    89 kept_same 
 9     3  2018    67 kept_same 
10     3  2019    87 improved  
11     3  2020    51 got_worse 
12     3  2021    65 improved
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to `break` the function at the first instance

```
check_grades_improvement <- function(grades){
  for(i in 2:length(grades)){
    if(grades[i] < grades[i-1]){
      return(FALSE)
      break
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

check_grades_decline <- function(grades){
  for(i in 2:length(grades)){
    if(grades[i] > grades[i-1]){
      return(FALSE)
      break
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
```

-testing

```
 my_data %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(check_grades_improvement(grade)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(id) %>%
   unique()
# A tibble: 1 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     1


my_data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(check_grades_decline(grade)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(id) %>% 
   unique()
# A tibble: 1 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     2
```

---

Or if it is for all instances

```
my_data %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(c(FALSE, diff(grade) > 0)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(id) %>%
  unique
# A tibble: 2 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     1
2     3
my_data %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(c(FALSE, diff(grade) < 0)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(id) %>%
  unique
# A tibble: 2 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     2
2     3
```